# Changed Resource URL setting, now can't access Civi on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php, resource-urls

I've been getting 404s on public pages due to my directory setup, so I changed the default Resource URL in **Administer >> System Settings >> Resource URLs**
from the default ([civicrm.files]?)
to the URL for my civi directory.

I now can't get back to reset it to the default.

I've tried overriding the Resource URL in settings.php to:

```
http://mysite.org/mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/
```

but that doesnt work.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I'd revisit this once you have implemented Kevin's suggestions in http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16643/changed-resource-url-setting-now-cant-access-civi-on-wordpress - doing so should clear this issue up.

Comment: @Christian you have linked to this question. I think you mean http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/16658/127

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to return the settings back to default.

I believe that the default settings for WordPress (in Administer >> System Settings >> Resource URLs) are as follows:

- CiviCRM Resource URL: [civicrm.root]/
- Image Upload URL: [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/
- Custom CSS URL: (blank)
- Extension Resource URL: [civicrm.files]/ext/

You would typically only need to override the Resource URL in civicrm.settings.php if you have moved your site. I suggest that you set this back to how it was previously.

You may want to post a separate question about the problems you are having with 404s if this is still an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

To change the Resource URL back to the default, would I just change the entry in settings.php to [civicrm.root]/ ? Or do it need to change it elsewhere?

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify that these settings are for the user interface (Administer >> System Settings >> Resource URLs).  I suggest that you change your civicrm.settings.php file back to what you had previously.  I believe this setting is an override that you have added in, so you should just be able to remove it to get back to where you were before.

Comment: Thanks both. 

William, unfortunately I'm unable to access the user interface to make the changes. 

Karin, I've tried your recommendation, but without much luck. 

I think for now I'll just do a fresh install and take it from there.

Comment: @Cowcross are you unable to access the CiviCRM user interface at all?  If so, I think that you may have made other changes to the civicrm.settings.php file.  Do you have a backup of the previous working version of this file?  If so, I would suggest that you restore that version.