# 404 errors for loading CSS on Event pages (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, civievent, registration, css

I'm using a fresh install of Civi 4.7.15 on Wordpress 4.7.1

I can use the back-end of Civi fine, but when I try to load public pages - e.g. Event Registration Page, the page can't load the necessary CSS and JS files (hangs for a long time and then displays wrong).

I believe it's somethng to do with paths - my Wordpress install is at: `http://mysite.org/mysite/wp-content`

(but points to `http://mysite.org/` as the default address)

When Civi tries to load the scripts, it looks for the files in `http://mysite.org/mysite/mysite/`

Changing the Base URL to just `http://mysite.org/` fixes the public pages but breaks the back-end.

Is there somewhere I can change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have WP installed in it's own directory as per https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

The short answer is that this is not (yet) supported by CiviCRM.  We've been documenting it here:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/WordPress+installed+in+its+own+directory+issues

The issue is tracked here : https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16421

For now I would move WP out of it's own directory, it may not be your optimum configuration, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would moving the wp-content directory make a difference? (as outlined here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder)

Comment: With CiviCRM 4.7.x the wp-content directory can be moved.