# Events link outside of civicrm admin area does not work in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I installed wordpress in a directory that is not root. I later installed Civicrm. From within the admin area I am able to access the events without any issue. when I use the test link to access an event it works. However when I use the live link, it goes to the wrong address. What do I need to change to get the live links to work outside of civicrm admin area?

Example:
Working link
http://akhawaty.org/aiw/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&id=7&reset=1

Nonworking link
http://akhawaty.org/aiw/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=7

Answer (score 0):

I believe that installing CiviCRM with WordPress in a different directory is not fully supported.

See this answer: [404 errors for loading CSS on Event pages (Wordpress)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/404-errors-for-loading-css-on-event-pages-wordpress/16658#16658)

The list of issues are documented on this page in the Wiki: [WordPress installed in its own directory issues](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/WordPress+installed+in+its+own+directory+issues)

If possible, I would suggest that you install WordPress in the root directory.

Comment: I am not getting a 404 error. It is taking me to a blog post, or a page on my website versus to the actual registration. the URL for testing the registration actually works. I was able to manipulate where the URL should go to actually register For example: [link](http://akhawaty.org/aiw1/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=1)

It looks like a bug existed for this issue before, and there was a work around, but now with the updated wordpress the issue has returned.